# How can I listen to valueChanges and setValue of a AbstractControl in reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I am new to Angular and I have a Reactive Forms with  `AbstractControl` that subscribe for `valueChange` to listen for any values change in input field. Inside the subscribed function I want to change the value of the input under a certain condition.

```
this.abstractControl.valueChanges.subscribe(data => {
...
   if(.....) {
       this.formGroup.patchValue({
           name: result
       )}
    }
...
}
```

I tried to use `this.abstractControl.setValue(result)` does'nt work too.

I get an error in setting the value.

```
ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

What is the recommended way of listening to a value change and changing the value accord to a condtion?

Comment: Post a complete minimal example, as a plunkr, reproducing the problem. My guess is that you're causing an infinite loop, where each change causes an event to be emitted, which causes a change, which causes an event to be emitted, etc.

Comment: You need to set the value "quietly", or setting the value triggers the subscription which sets the value which... Have you read https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#setValue?

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks. it helps to resolve my problem with emitEvent: false.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks ur guess is correct

Answer (score 15, accepted):

@jonrsharpe thanks. Problem resolved with `emitEvent: false`.

Read: [angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#setValue](http://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#setValue)